# Connect to the facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to connect to the Facebook Login through api, I can Login and get information but everything is from Facebook:

here is my code how can I write this code return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
to

```
return [[[HttpRequest sharedHttpRequest] session] handleOpenURL:url];
```

I should have session.activeSession, but if I right it like this I will have an error

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
{

//return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];

// return [[[HttpRequest sharedHttpRequest] session] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

would you please help me to implement this method,

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE :**
It never use the url and stringByAppendingString:@"connect-fb"

I can login and I can get information but it never use api for example it works with this  NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"connect-fb"]; and also if I put what ever I want in stringByAppendingString:@"everything"

Here is my method for login and connect to api:

```
 -(void) getApiUserInfos
{

if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,

       NSError *error) {

         if (!error) {

             NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"connect-fb"];
             NSLog(@"%@",url);
             NSString *post = [NSString 
 stringWithFormat:@"facebookId=%@&firstName=%@&lastName=%@&email=%@",
                               self.facebookId = user.id,
                               self.firstName= user.first_name,
                               self.lastName= user.last_name,
                               self.email=user.email];

             NSLog(@"post : %@",post);
             post = [post stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [post UTF8String] length: [post 
 lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

             NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
 URLWithString:url]

                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                                timeoutInterval:600];

             [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
             [request setHTTPBody:postData];

             [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue 
 alloc] init]
                                    completionHandler:
              ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {


                  return;

                  if(error)
                  {
                      NSLog(@"Errorr");
                  }

                  ///write for if error
                    NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];


                  NSLog(@"api yser infos RETSTRING : %@",ret);


              }];                 
         }
     }];
   }
```

Comment: What do you use for BASE_URL?

Comment: @rokjarc #define BASE_URL @"http://test.test.com/app_dev.php/api/"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that import libraries in your code?

```
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "Facebook.h"
```

Comment: what error ? have you verified bundle identifier in facebook app at facebook.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you allready have your app's `FacebookAppId`.

Let's say it is: `123456789012345`

You have to enter in YourApp-Info.plist.

Under keys:

`FacebookAppId` as `123456789012345`

`URLTypes` - `Item0` - `UrlSchemes` - `Item0` as `fb123456789012345`

Then your open url should be:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{

    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can try using the alternative method of fetching user data. Works perfectly for me.

```
- (void)fetchUserData
{
    NSLog (@"fetching user data");


    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                NSLog (@"FB:          id: %@", user.id);
                NSLog (@"FB:    username: %@", user.username);
                NSLog (@"FB:        link: %@", user.link);
                NSLog (@"FB:        name: %@", user.name);
                NSLog (@"FB:  first_name: %@", user.first_name);
                NSLog (@"FB:   last_name: %@", user.last_name);
                NSLog (@"FB: middle_name: %@", user.middle_name);
                NSLog (@"FB:    birthday: %@", user.birthday);
                NSLog (@"FB:       email: %@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                NSLog (@"FB:      gender: %@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog (@"fetchUserData: error");
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Not the final solution, just a step forward:

I modified your request creation to:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"facebookId=%@&firstName=%@&lastName=%@&email=%@",
                                  self.facebookId = user.id,
                                  self.firstName = user.first_name,
                                  self.lastName = user.last_name,
                                  self.email = [user objectForKey:@"email"]]; //this line changed
```

And completion handler to:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    //return; - ditch this

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); // returns "unsuported URL"
    }
    else
    {
         NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];

         NSLog(@"api yser infos RETSTRING : %@",ret);
    }            
}];
```

Comment: Yes I know but it never goes to my api let me update my question

Comment: According to the simptoms you are describing it seems that here should be the problem. Or something with registration of your app on developers.facebook.com. Recheck your App ID/API Key.

Comment: I don't see your login implementation in there. Does your app login successfully and you just can't get the info or you can't login at all?

Comment: I can login and I can get information but it never use api for example it works with this  NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"connect-fb"]; and also if I put what ever I want in stringByAppendingString:@"everything"

Comment: Sorry, i just noticed that you are doing the same. I'll try to see if i get same errors with your code.

Comment: Rightnow I don't have any error I just want to use this NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"connect-fb"];

Comment: my problem is here : NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"connect-fb"];

Comment: yes, but stringByAppendingPathComponent also results with "unsupported URL". I dont think http://test.test.com/app_dev.php/api/connect-fb exists.